# Rstudio auto-completion, undefined options for data columns

Tags: r, autocomplete, rstudio

With my Rstudio, let's say I create a data frame called data.

```
data = data.frame(a=rep(0,100),b=rep(1,100))
```

Then, if I input `data$` and click tab for auto-completion, it shows options as: `a` , `b` (column names as defined in data as expected) that I can choose from.

But if I input `data$` within a function, say I input `unique(data$` and then click tab, it shows options as: `GermanCredit`, `cars`, `dhfr`,... (which are not as expected. I don't know where they are from.)

In my global environment, there are no such data as `GermanCredit` or `cars`.

If I create my data using a different name say

```
data2 = data.frame(a=rep(0,100),b=rep(1,100))
```

then, I don't get this trouble.

**Q: I am wondering what is going on here and how I can address the issue so once I click on tab, it will only show the columns that I actually defined in my data.**

Just in case, I have installed the following packages in my RStudio:

```
grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  base     

pryr_0.1.2       e1071_1.6-7      caret_6.0-52     gridExtra_2.0.0  
boot_1.3-17      lmtest_0.9-34    zoo_1.7-12       PairedData_1.0.1 
ggplot2_1.0.1    lattice_0.20-33  mvtnorm_1.0-3    gld_2.3.1        MASS_7.3-43
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: type `?data`. `data` is a function in R which gives you access to a bumch of stored data sets. I would actually advise against naming your dataframe `data` and settle for something else like `df`